# Angular Unit Test - Comparison of Array of Objects still fails with toEqual

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm quite aware about the difference of **toBe** and **toEqual** in a test so I thought my setup would run smoothly but it still fails due to 'type problems'. This simplified setup still represents the problem:

My Component looks like (excerpt):

```
let testVar: Employee[] = [];

...

convertEmpArr(input) {
  const employeeUpd: Employee[] = [];
  employeeUpd.push(new Employee(9999, 'Boss'));
  for (const item of input) {
    employeeUpd.push(new Employee(item.id, item.name));
  }
  this.testVar = employeeUpd;
}
```

While employee is build like this:

```
export class Employee {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {
    }
}
```

So I wanted to check if the updated Data has the extra line **AND** the right data. I'm using mocked Datasets for it:

```
  it('convertEmpArr - should add Boss and other Employees dynamically', () => {
    const mockEmpIn: Employee[] = [
      {id: 0, name: "Smith"}
    ];
    const mockEmpOut: Employee[] = [
      {id: 9999, name: "Boss"},
      {id: 0, name: "Smith"}
    ];
    component.convertEmpArr(mockEmpIn);
    expect(component.testVar).toEqual(mockEmpOut);
    expect(component.testVar.length).toBe(2);
  });
```

The second expect works fine but the first expect fails with:

```
Expected $[0] to be a kind of Object, but was Employee({ id: 9999, name: 'Boss' }).
Expected $[1] to be a kind of Object, but was Employee({ id: 0, name: 'Smith' }).
```

I thought that using **toEqual** is exactly for this usecase. Using something like this will work but I still would like to know why my test fails with the **original setup** - I hope someone can fill me in:

```
expect(JSON.stringify(component.testVar)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(mockEmpIn));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why **toEqual** doesn't work for your assertion, is because even though the objects `mockEmpOut` and `component.testVar` are "equal", they are NOT "the same", since they represent objects that live in different locations in memory. **toEqual** returns false if the object references belong to two different objects in memory.

The minute we write the below statement, it creates a new object in memory.

```
const mockEmpOut: Employee[] = [
      {id: 9999, name: "Boss"},
      {id: 0, name: "Smith"}
    ];
```

The resultant object generated in the `convertEmpArr()` method will ALWAYS reside at a different memory location as compared to the `mockEmpOut` object declared in your test because they are initialized at two different places and are not related in any way.  Hence, the **toEqual** comparison always returns false in this scenario.

You could either use the JSON.stringify() approach that you have already mentioned OR you could assert that the values of the different fields generated in the resultant object, match the values of the object that you are passing in the input.

Comment: And how should be the test solution?